# Access container url using Azure Blob Emulator

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, azure-emulator

I'm trying to use a Azure Emulator to create a container, but I think is not working:

Emulator Endpoint :

```
BlobEndpoint: http://127.0.0.1:10000/
```

App.config :

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true;" />
</appSettings>
```

And the code :

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
                   CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
```

But when I try to access `http://127.0.0.1:10000/mycontainer` I got :

```
The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.
```

Comment: I suppose it should be http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/mycontainer ?

Comment: Thanks, it works, the problem is when I tried to access, I thought is going to list or something!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct container URI should be http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/mycontainer, how did you try to access it? I don't think opening it in browser directly is feasible.

Comment: If i type the right Url with the file extension it works.